# How do you show an animated progress bar and animated command line in VimScript?

Tags: vim

I'm wondering how you could get the same moving progress bar you see 
when you run `:TOhtml` on a big file using VimScript.

Also, when you do `:vimgrep`, you can see the files displayed in
succession in the command window. How does one create this kind of
progressive command window update using VimScript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1822619/how-to-send-status-to-the-vim-status-line-after-calling-custom-vim-python-funct). It might lead you in the right direction. You're likely interested in the echo command `:help echo`